# Can't access items in array after loading from API

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am loading data from Django into a ReactJS frontend. When I log the imported data, it shows that it is an array but when I render the data, it just displays a stream of numbers.

```
const url = "http://localhost:8000/api/Data/"
const [data] = LoadData(url);

var val1 = data.angle

console.log(val1)

return(
    <div>
        {val1}
    </div>
)
```

console

```
Array(432) [ 275, 306, 84, 62, 189, 228, 63, 18, 6, 134, … ]
```

What is rendered

```
27530684621892286318613452312
```

Comment: what do you want to show/render?

Comment: You are directly dumping the array into the template, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: the array. I'm expecting ```[ 275, 306, 84, 62, 189, 228, 63, 18, 6, 134, … ]```

Comment: My final goal is to take that array and put it in a graph to visualize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val1` is an array

If you want to display `[ 275, 306, 84, 62, 189, 228, 63, 18, 6, 134, … ]` you can combine the values with `.join`.

```js
const url = "http://localhost:8000/api/Data/"
const [data] = LoadData(url);

var val1 = data.angle

console.log(val1)

return(
    <div>
        [ {val1.join(', ')} ]
    </div>
)
```

Otherwise if you want to create one div per item then have a look at the [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) React documentation. Maybe something like this:

```js
const url = "http://localhost:8000/api/Data/"
const [data] = LoadData(url);

var val1 = data.angle

console.log(val1)

const listItems = val1.map((item) =>
  <div>{item}</div>
);

return(
    <div>
        {listItems}
    </div>
)
```

If the end goal is to visualize the data, then instead you could use a visualization/charts library such as https://apexcharts.com/docs/react-charts/

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
  <div>
        <ul>
          {val1.map((val) => {
            return <li>val</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
  </div>
```